# iphone link error

Tags: iphone, xcode, hyperlink

i got this link error when i tried to install my app to device:

```
ldr 12-bit displacement out of range (4628 max +/-4096) in _ABAddressBookCreate$stub in    _ABAddressBookCreate$stub from
```

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

how can i solve this? in simulator there is no error. i search everywhere, there is no "ABAddressBookCreate" in my code. i 've added the AddressBookUI and AddressBook framework in my project but i did not change anything in it.

Any idea what is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue.

I used third party library in my project. I added Other Linker Flags in build settings of Target.

While setting build settings, please set the Configuration to "All Configuration". Because it was the problem in my project. I'd added Other Linker Flags to build setting while the Configuration is in "Debug".

I didn't get any issue in simulator. But while running in the device I got the same error `ldr 12-bit displacement out of range (4628 max +/-4096) in _ABAddressBookCreate$stub in    _ABAddressBookCreate$stub from`

After that I removed the third party library from the project then added again to my project.
While adding Other Linker Flags in build settings I set Configuration to "All Configuration"
Solved.